# Robonomics parachain on zombienet times out

Tags: parachain, zombienet

I have a minimum zombienet configuration with two validators on local rococo testnet and a robonomics parachain node.

```
[relaychain]
default_command = "./bin/polkadot"
default_args = [ "-lparachain=debug" ]

chain = "rococo-local"

    [[relaychain.nodes]]
    name = "alice"
    validator = true

    [[relaychain.nodes]]
    name = "bob"
    validator = true

[[parachains]]
id = 2048
chain = "main-dev"

    [parachains.collator]
    name = "alice"
    chain = "main-dev"
    command = "./bin/robonomics"
    args = ["-lparachain=debug","--force-authoring"]
```

The relay chain spawns alright but the robonomics parachain fails with

```
Error: Timeout(60) for node : alice-1
at NativeClient.<anonymous> (/snapshot/javascript/packages/orchestrator/dist/providers/native/nativeClient.js)
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
at fulfilled (/snapshot/javascript/packages/orchestrator/dist/providers/native/nativeClient.js)
```

Chain versions

robonomics 2.6.0-84120838070

polkadot 0.9.28-314298c32ac

I have tried the similar configuration with other parachains and it works.

Comment: Hi can you include the link to the repo of robonomics to try to reproduce? Also, can you check the logs of the collator? you need to find the log file in the temp directory for the namespace.

Comment: I added the issue at the zombienet repository. https://github.com/paritytech/zombienet/issues/620